# Database without Server Side Scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to make a web page that can handle permanent storage of information without involving any server side scripting.

What I would preferably like to do is have an SQLite database in the same directory as index.htm and manipulate/interrogate the data using JQuery. I have found tutorials in doing something similar with html 5 but unfortunately the environment I'm forced to make it in requires support for IE8 and this isn’t optional.

SQLite isn’t a specific requirement, it could quite easily be a CSV file or XML. Can someone recommend a good method for doing so? I know the requirements aren’t ideal normally I would do PHP and MySQL but alas...

Nothing complicated required for data storage, just something similar to the following.

```
|-----|------|------|------|
|Index|Value1|value2|value3|
|-----|------|------|------|
|1    |moo   |100   |1101  |
|2    |choo  |150   |1102  |
|3    |foo   |200   |1103  |
|-----|------|------|------|
```

Comment: Would you like to share how did you accomplished this task then?

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 saves it on the client without server side scripting. You can do the same in older browser versions using cookies but the amount of storage is limited by comparison to HTML 5 solutions. Your suggestion of storing in the same directory as index.htm is possible, but index.htm is on the server side and will require a small amount of server side scripting to bind the data from javascript to your database of choice. SQL lite is an option on many, perhaps most web server configurations.

As a tangent, typically, you do not persist data in a web facing directory. Only server side scripts or files that you explicitly want the world to be able to download face the outside. Client data that is stored on the server is normally adjacent to web root, not under it as index.htm is.